# Neg Binomial and the Jeffreys' Prior

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, prior

I'm trying to obtain the Jeffreys' prior for a negative binomial distribution. I can't see where I go wrong, so if someone could help point that out that would be appreciated.

Okay, so the situation is this: I am to compare the prior distributions obtained using a binomial and a negative binomial, where (in both cases) there are $n$ trials and $m$ successes. I get the right answer for the binomial case, but not for the negative binomial.

Let's call the Jeffreys' prior $\pi_J(\theta)$. Then,

$$
\pi_J(\theta)\propto [I(\theta)]^{1/2}.
$$

Under the regularity conditions (fulfilled as we are dealing with the exponential family),

$$
I(\theta)=-E\left(\frac{\partial^2 \log L(\theta|x)}{\partial \theta^2}\right)
$$
where for the negative binomial $n$ is $x$ in the above expression (the total number of successes $m$ is fixed, $n$ is not). The distribution --I think-- is

$$
p(m|\theta)\propto\theta^m(1-\theta)^{n-m}
$$
since $\theta$ is defined as the probability of success and $m$ is the number of successes. This is also the likelihood, since $m$ is a scalar and not a vector. Hence,

$$
L(\theta|n)\propto\theta^m(1-\theta)^{n-m}\\
\log L(\theta|n)=m\log\theta +(n-m)\log (1-\theta)\\
\frac{\partial\log L(\theta|n)}{\partial \theta}=\frac{m}{\theta}-\frac{n-m}{1-\theta}\\
\frac{\partial^2\log L(\theta|n)}{\partial \theta^2}=-\frac{m}{\theta^2}-\frac{n-m}{(1-\theta)^2}
$$
so the Fisher information is

$$
I(\theta)=-E\left(\frac{\partial^2\log L(\theta|n)}{\partial \theta^2}\right)=\frac{m}{\theta^2}+\frac{E(n)-m}{(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{m}{\theta^2}+\frac{\frac{m\theta}{1-\theta}-m}{(1-\theta)^2}\\
=\frac{m(1-\theta)^2+\frac{m\theta^3}{(1-\theta)}-m\theta^2}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}=\frac{m(1-2\theta)+\frac{m\theta^3}{(1-\theta)}}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^2}\\
=\frac{m(1-2\theta)(1-\theta)+m\theta^3}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^3}=\frac{m(1-3\theta+2\theta^2+\theta^3)}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^3}\\
\propto\frac{1-3\theta+2\theta^2+\theta^3}{\theta^2(1-\theta)^3}
$$

This, however, does not give me the correct answer. The correct answer is

$$
\pi_J(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\theta(1-\theta)^{1/2}}
$$
which means that the Information I get should be

$$
I(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2(1-\theta)}
$$
since the prior should be proportional to the square root of the information.

Can anyone find any mistakes? I wouldn't be surprised if I screwed something up with the set up of the distribution (successes vs failures with their respective probabilities, etc).

I used the expected value from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) and I know the correct answer from [here (page 3)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture10.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The problem arises because the negative binomial distribution can be parametrized differently.** As a consequence, the expectation differs for different parametrizations. The way you have specified the negative binomial distribution, the expectation of $n$ is $E(n) = m/\theta$ (e.g. see [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180219125451/https://www.ida.liu.se/%7E732A46/2012/OtherMaterial/SolutionsExam1.pdf) on page 3). With that, the Fisher information simplifies to $$I(\theta) = m\left(\frac{1}{\theta^2(1-\theta)}\right)$$

Thus the Jeffreys' prior is
$$
\pi_{J}(\theta) = |I(\theta)|^{1/2}\propto \theta^{-1}(1-\theta)^{-1/2}
$$

as you already noted.

Comment: Terrific! That's very helpful and also an excellent reference as it goes through the very problem I was struggling with. Thank you!

Comment: I've found a solution that uses another formulation, see [here](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~brani/isyebayes/bank/Quiz71.pdf). Glad I could help. You're welcome.

Comment: Archived version of the (now dead) link in the answer: http://web.archive.org/web/20180219125451/https://www.ida.liu.se/~732A46/2012/OtherMaterial/SolutionsExam1.pdf