# Jeffreys's prior for negative binomial regresion

Tags: bayesian, negative-binomial-distribution, jeffreys-prior

For a negative biomial model, where $Y_i \sim \text{NegBin}(\mu_i, \kappa)$
$$\mu_i:=\log EY_i = \mathbf{x_i} \mathbf{\beta} + \log t_i,$$
is the form of Jeffreys's prior known/published in some way that one could easily implement it e.g. in Stan?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58099/neg-binomial-and-the-jeffreys-prior obviously it doesn't cover the stan part but that by itself would probably be off topic

Comment: Are you assuming $\kappa$ is known?

Comment: @jbownan unknown $\kappa$, unknown betas.

Comment: @Chaconne That’s for the formulation in terms of “how many tries until m successes” - not the mean rate per time unit + dispersion version. I suppose maybe re-parameterizing should give the answer for the case with just an intercept? But what about the regression setting?